# localize image dynamically through code in objective C

Tags: objective-c, localization

How can i localize the image which I have downloaded from website?

I know how to localize image in the resources through IDE. But I don't know how to localize the image which is downloaded from the website.

Is there any way to localize the downloaded image?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Developing Localized iPhone Applications](http://www.pushplay.net/blog_detail.php?id=33)

If you're d/ling images from the web, cache them in the Caches or Documents folder with a localized name.

Comment: Thanks very much. This approach is great:For example:

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString (@"logo_en.png", @"Logo Image")];

This way, it will default to using logo_en.png, but different language files can use other logos if you have them. For example, you can change the French file to have:

/* Logo Image */
"logo_en.png" = "logo_fr.png";

...but the Japanese file could simply default to the English logo (for example, if you didn't have a Japanese-specific logo).